# alternate approach to send request to server fast and reliable

Tags: java, connection

I have my standalone java program which is sending some data to server. I am using the get method to send the request.

```
            try {   
                URL url = new URL(URL + "?prak=" + urlParameters);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(false);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.connect();
                int code = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
                    System.out.println("success");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("failed");
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception occur" + e.getMessage() );

            }
```

The success rate of this connection is nearly 70%. As i need to send the data fast so i am using timout of only 1000. I dont want to increase the timeout.
And due to this it is throwing timeout exception. Please suggest me any more reliable and fast way to establish the connection.

Comment: It's most likely because the connection to the webserver you are contacting is slow.

Comment: How can i use websocket. I need to create connection from my java standalone program to server which is not possible by websocket. Also I don't need any duplex connection.